# ajax error return - not returning variable

Tags: ajax, django

I am new to ajax so hopefully this is a simple oversight.

I have the following code for upvotes, based off the django updown app

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#custom-post-up").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $form=$('#custom-post-up');
        var datastring = $form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            dataType: 'html',
            data: datastring,
            success: function(result)
            {
                $('#custom-post-message').html(result);
                $('#custom-post-rating').load('/post/{{ id }}/rating/');
            },
            error: function(result)
            {
                $('#custom-post-message').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
   });
});
```

The problem - the error message doesn't get produced. if I put in a string instead, it works fine.
eg:

```
error: function(result)
            {
                $('#custom-post-message').html("error");
            }
```

Also, the success message works fine too.

The error message I am trying to get is from the view in the updown app:

```
def authentication_required_response(self, request, context):
    response = HttpResponse('You must be logged in to vote.')
    response.status_code = 403
    return response
```

The success message from this view works fine:

```
def rating_changed_response(self, request, context):
    response = HttpResponse('Vote changed.')
    return response
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `result` when you get an error on the server side? Try: `console.log(result)` in the JavaScript to see what's going on.

Comment: Getting: Object { readyState=4, responseText="You must be logged in to vote.", status=403, more...}

Comment: Are you parsing your response to `JSON` ? Shouldn't you trying to access to the result key you need ? Something like `result['responseText'] ` ?

Comment: @Liarez - that did it, thanks! If you want to answer the question, I'll mark your answer as correct. Appreciate if you could add a short explanation too of the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 things you should remember using AJAX:

1. If you receive a dictionary through answer, access to the key you need
2. Parse the response AJAX is receiving

## Access to the key you need

It seems you're sending a dictionary through your variable `result`. You receive the AJAX response through:

```
...   ...   ...
success: function(result)
    {
        $('#custom-post-message').html(result);
        $('#custom-post-rating').load('/post/{{ id }}/rating/');
    },

...  ... ...
```

And you're doing  `$('#custom-post-message').html(result);` but result is a **dictionary**:

```
result = { readyState=4, responseText="You must be logged in to vote.", status=403, more...}
```

and you need to access using a key like:

```
result['responseText'] 
result['readyState']
result['status']
```

## Parse the response AJAX is receiving

This mean that when you send the response to AJAX function you can pass a string . You need to send the response parsed to JSON.

In my Django projects, I use a JSON function to parse ( `json.dump(variable)` ) and `json.loads(variable)` to unparse